# Third-party API wrapper in Java: how to design

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, api

Suppose, there's a site that provides an API, such as this:

- Users post questions, answers on that site
- You can make `GET` and
  `POST` calls
- There are two types of authentication: **weak** (only gives
  read rights) and **strong** (gives both read and write rights)
- Right now, I'd like to read users' questions and answers (only need weak access) and send them messages or post my own questions in the future (would need strong access)
- The site's API has actions **both** to do with users (e.g. send a message) and with site in general (see about, see most popular questions)

What I have right now looks like this:

```
public class Wrapper  {
   private AccessToken accessToken;

   public Wrapper(...)  {
     //does some stuff
     //gets access token:
     getAccessToken(...);
   }    

   public AccessToken getAccessToken(...)  {
      AccessToken result;
      //gets access token, given the auth info provided as arguments
      accessToken = result;

      return result; 
   }

   public ArrayList<Question> getQuestions(User user)  {
       //gets user's questions, using the accessToken field
       //set's a user's questions field to the result and returns the result
   }

   public ArrayList<Answer> getAnswers(User user)  {
       //same as previous
   }

   public boolean sendMessage(User user)  {
      //sends a message, if current accessToken is strong
   }
}
```

and **User** class:

```
class User  {
  private String username;

  private ArrayList<Question> questions;
  private ArrayList<Answer> answers;

  public User(String username) {this.username=username;}    

  //getters and setters
}
```

So, to use it you would use something like this:

```
public class Main  {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
     Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(...);
     ArrayList<Question> questions = wrapper.getQuestions(new User("username"));
     wrapper.sendMessage(new User("username2"));
  }
}
```

I have issues with this.

First of all, class `User` feels superfluous, since all the functionality is inside the `Wrapper` class.

Second, I wonder if what my methods do is wright - from the design's perspective: in `getAccessToken` I **both** return `AccessToken` **and** set a `Wrapper`'s field `accessToken` to the result. Is this the right approach? Or should the method **only** return access token and then that result should be assigned to a class' field explicitly? Same goes for the `getQuestions` and `getAnswers` methods: they **both** get the `ArrayList`s, return them **and** assign a `User`'s field to the result - all inside the single method.

I would like for a `User` class to have some meaning. I thought of doing it something like that:

```
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper(...);

    User user = new User("username");
    user.getQuestions(wrapper.getAccessToken());
    user.sendMessage(wrapper.getAccessToken());
```

So, the `Wrapper` class would only serve as a place to get an access token from, which doesn't feel right as well. I could place the access token functionality inside the `User` class and use it like this:

```
     User user = new User("username", ...);
     user.getQuestions();
     user.sendMessage();
```

The `User`'s constructor would take both username and auth data, would get access token and store it inside a user and then use it when getting questions/answers or sending messages. I could make the `accessToken` field inside `User` class `static` so that all users shared the same token.

However, there are actions the site API provides, that aren't obviously connected with users: for instance, getting the site's most popular questions. It feels right to use a generic `Wrapper` class for that purpose which contradicts with the previous approach.

I'm new to this and only know a couple design patterns. Perhaps, there are widespread patterns that are to be used for this type of problem? Any help/advice is appreciated.